# SQL query to calculate SLA from 3 columns

Tags: sql, if-statement

Having trouble with my SQL Query
I would like to display Late or OnTime depending on the time difference between 3 Columns
Rules: Calculate Loaded with Finished if Deferred is NULL otherwise calculate deferred with Finished.

```
SELECT keyvalue, loaded, finished, deferred,
      If Deferred is NULL
          Case
        when DATEDIFF(minute,loaded,finished) > 720
        Then 'Late'
        else 'OnTime'
    end SLA
        Else
               DATEDIFF(minute,deferred,finished) > 720
  FROM ItemTable
```

Output:
KeyValue - SLA (late/OnTime)

Comment: What version of SQL?  You might want to edit your tags to include that.  Also some sample date, and expected outputs.   Also what issue are you having? e.g. what is wrong with your current select? Having trouble is not descriptive

Comment: You realize that `datediff()` doesn't count whole minutes?

Comment: `case when Deferred is null and dateadd(hour, 12, loaded) < finished then 'Late' else 'On Time' end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
Select keyvalue, loaded, finished, deferred,
      Case When Deferred Is not null Then 
            IIF(DATEDIFF(minute,deferred,finished) > 720,'Late','OnTime')
        Else IIF(DATEDIFF(minute,loaded,finished) > 720,'Late','OnTime')
        end SLA
    From ItemTable
```